# Intution that lies in the recursive solution to the Decode Ways problem

Tags: python, recursion

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-decodings-given-digit-sequence/

In ths problem above, it asks me to count the number of possible decodings of the given digit sequence.

In the question, 1 represent ‘A’, 2 represents ‘B’, etc. Given a digit sequence.

The problem can be solved recursively and we can recur for two subproblems.

```
1) If the last digit is non-zero, recur for remaining (n-1) digits and add the result to total count.

2) If the last two digits form a valid character (or smaller than 27), recur for remaining (n-2) digits and add the result to total count.
```

I do get the idea, but I don't totally understand why it's solved this way.

The code that I wrote based on the solutions above gives me the correct answer.

```
def numDecode(s):
    if len(s) == 0 or len(s) == 1: return 1
    count = 0
    if s[n - 1] > '0':
        count = numDecode(s[:n-1])
    if s[n - 2] == '1' or (s[n - 2] == '2' and s[n - 1] < '7'):
        count += rec(s[:n-2])
    return count
```

However, I still don't grasp the intuition behind this solution. Why are we starting from the back? And why are we breaking it into two subproblem that takes last one and two digits?

What would be the best way to approach when I solve this kind of problems in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: "problemThe c"?? Your question title doesn't make sense.

Comment: What's `rec`? Your code doesn't appear to be complete. Starting from the back is arbitrary--you can just as easily start from the front. The intuition behind DP is breaking large problems down into small, overlapping ones and storing the results so you don't need to re-compute each subproblem. In this case, if you know the ways of decoding some subset of the string, you memoize it and never re-compute it. The base cases are if you have no elements, there are no ways to decode. If you have one element, there is 1 way to decode it.